# Geometry - convex flanked by two circle rotate around geometrical center

Tags: algorithm, geometry

I want to do it that a convex(consist of some line or arc) rotate around it's geometrical center(*Cx,Cy*). Meanwhile the convex flanked by two circle (given by radius: R and left center:(*Lx,Cy*), right center:(*Rx,Cy*) ). It means the circle center with same X axis as geometrical(*Cy*).

The model picture:

[image: Figure 1]

The algorithm aims to calculate the *Lx* and *Rx* when rotate *theta*(0 to 360 degree) and the convex with two circle only have one contact point separately. How can I achieve it?

Assume we can get the convex discretization points by given delta distance or delta *theta* around geometrical center.

Answer (score 0):

To provide contact between rotated convex and circle, it is worth to define convex pieces analytically.

For example, if straight segment has parametric equation

```
X = X0 + t * (X1-X0)
Y = Y0 + t * (Y1-Y0)
```

then solve equation system

```
(X - Lx)^2 + (Y - Cy)^2 = R^2             //distance
(X - Lx) * (X1 - X0) + (Y - Cy) * (Y1 - Y0) = 0    //tangent perpendicularity to radius
```

for unknowns t and Lx and check that t lies in range 0..1. If true - circle touches this segment, Lx if valid

If curved segment is analytical curve, then normal to the curve in touch point should be collinear with radius.

For circle arc segment with radius aR and center ax, ay tangency condition is:

```
 (ax - Lx)^2 + (ay - Cy)^2 = (aR + R)^2
```

again - one need to check whether tangent point is inside arc limits

Comment: em...I want to get Lx and Rx when the convex rotate *theta* (0 to 360 angle), not just lie at 0 angle.In the other word, rotate every 0.1 angle or smaller, I want to get every Lx and Rx.

Comment: So you want Lx instantly changes to provide contact?

Comment: By the way, it is not the max euclidean distance to get Lx , Rx ; consider circle tangent with line not at the start point or end point.

Comment: I thought task is to find the rightmost Lx static position for free rotation of convex

Comment: yes, *theta* is independent variable , *Lx , Rx* are dependent variable , and R is an argument given by user.

Comment: where is the rotate *theta* go ?

Comment: In coordinates of segment ends and arc centers

Comment: em...I know the *ax* multiply rotate matrix , can get *ax θ*. But line segment how to deal it, what is your 't' means? line's rake ratio ?

Comment: parameter in range 0..1 denotes relative position of point at the segment. To rotate segment - just rotate its end points

Comment: I can't totally understand "To rotate segment just rotate its end points"...the line's start points why not need? BTW, it is hard to calculate the four variables equation...

Comment: Of course, I meant both start and end points. Equation system is for two unknowns (but it is not quadratic, not linear)